# Compute sum and output sum using while

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program is supposed to basically output the sum 1+2+3+4+5 and get 15 and then stop. However, it stops at 6 rather than 15. I know my while is `a<6` and not 15. Im trying to accomplish it going through 1+2+3+4+5 and stopping at 6 that way.

```
a=1
s=0
while a<6:
    s+=a
    a+=1
print (a)
```

Comment: try `((5+1)*5) // 2` to get sum of increasing integers up to 5 :) or use built-in `sum(range(1,6))`

Comment: You got much further than your [classmate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42284644/follow-steps-and-translate-to-python) did, but if your class could work together instead of posting a bunch of individual questions, that would be great.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 haha what?

Comment: Someone asked about this exact same problem an hour ago, got a negative reaction to his request for someone to do his homework, and deleted the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are printing your index `a` instead of `s`:

```
a=1
s=0
while a<6:
    s+=a
    a+=1
print(s)
```

using more descriptive variable names would have helped you to debug this code:

```
count=1
sum=0
while count<6:
    sum+=count
    count+=1
print(sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to print S (Since we need to print sum).

replace print(a) with print(s).

Answer (score 0):

In your case, your are printing the counter not the sum of the number so it's better to print(s) not print (a)

-To write it with a more convenient way with clear variables names

```
def sum(number):

     counter, sum = 1, 0
     while counter < number:

           sum += counter
           counter += 1
     return  sum


print sum(6)
```